# How to 'immediately' redirect in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

In a function, called by a certain controller action, I want to redirect the browser immediately  to another page without returning to the controller.  Anny suggestions?

Just to make it clear, look at the two following just-for-explanation functions inside a controller:

```
public function someAction ($value)
{
    $a = $this->myFunction($value);

    // I don't want to come here if something wrong with $value
}

public function myFunction ($value)
{
    if ($value == '')
    {
        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('someRoute'));
    }

    return 10;
}
```

Comment: You could have myFunction just toss an exception. I suppose if you really wanted to you could use the php header command and exit.  Not recommended.  Bottom line: you need to adjust your thinking a bit.  @White has the correct approach.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case I solved the problem by creating an event listerer for the controller.
This one is executed before each someAction().  I do my tests over there and if needed I redirect the user.
Looks a good solution for me because I don't need the myFunction() to check things anymore.

Comment: more details on how to do this would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Your `$this->redirect();` call created a `RedirectResponse` object ([API reference](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html)). Redirection will only happen if your controller actually returns this object.

```
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('someRoute'));
```

Just check what your function returns ;)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

public function someAction ($value)
{
    $a = $this->myFunction($value);
    if($a instanceof RedirectResponse) return $a;

    // You won't come here if something wrong with $value
}
```

Still, I think it'd be best for you to use something else as a return value : `instanceof` isn't pretty. For instance, C routines usually return -1 if something went wrong. You could do something similar, using NULL perhaps :

```
public function myFunction ($value)
{
    if ($value == '')
    {
        return NULL; // Or something else (as long as it is illogical for your function to return it).
    }

    return 10;
}

public function someAction ($value)
{
    $a = $this->myFunction($value);
    if(is_null($a)) return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('someRoute'));

    // You won't come here if something wrong with $value
}
```

**Note :** if you want `myFunction` to determine the route, just use different return values (negative numbers maybe?), and make it match routes back in your controller (if `myFunction` returns -1, then go to `route1`, if it returns -2, then got to `route2`, and so on). You can also make it return the route itself (check `is_string($a)` to see if `myFunction` returned a route).

Comment: Hi @JohnWHSmith, thanks for your respons.  I understand your explanation but I searching for a way to do redirection without returnig to someAction().  As you describe it, I have to test return value of myFunction() and that is exactly what i want to avoid.  (because in that case I have to change existing code in almost every controller action)

Comment: Redirection can only happen in the controller, as it's the component which controls the routing at this point. Symfony has called `someAction()`, therefore it is *waiting* for it to terminate before going on. You need to end `someAction()` if you want your program to go further. As I said : *Redirection will only happen if your controller actually returns this object.*

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect immediately like this:

```
$redirect = $this->redirect($redirectUrl);
$redirect->send();
exit;
```